# Replacement of an abstract class in custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, geturl

I read a lot of information on this issue, but have not found a solution. I need to change the function `getAddToCartUrl`, in class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`. Is there a way to make a substitution function module (without creating a copy of it in the local directory)? Rewrite method in the case Abstract classes does not work.

Comment: Base on the limited info you provided... you could try extending Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract in your custom module and  rewrite the logic in getAddToCartUrl(), then use layout.xml to point to your custom module block

Comment: zmage,I am not clear about your question, can you please tell me ,are you want to use Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract your custom module?

Comment: @R.S : I think you should post it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot rewrite abstract classes
What you need to do is rewrite the class that extends, and inherits the abstract class methods.

As an example:

`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`, so if you want to change the behaviour of `getAddToCartUrl` when you view a product, you'd rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`

Can you explain what it is that you are trying to do?

I personally think that you are trying to change the wrong method (it is too low level to change), but since I don't know your end-goal, I cannot really comment on that.

I'll continue with some thoughts, as it could help you re-evaluate your intended implementation, and possibly identify the right place to extend.

Lets assume that your intention is to change the url retrieved for all products, system wide.

Lets look at what goes on in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::getAddToCartUrl()`

```
public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = array())
{
    if ($product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($product)) {
        if (!isset($additional['_escape'])) {
            $additional['_escape'] = true;
        }
        if (!isset($additional['_query'])) {
            $additional['_query'] = array();
        }
        $additional['_query']['options'] = 'cart';

        return $this->getProductUrl($product, $additional);
    }
    return $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
}
```

We can see in the code above that it checks to see if we have a valid product (and some url params), and if so, flow goes to another method `getProductUrl`, or to a helper `checkout/cart`

Great, lets go look at `getProductUrl` first:

```
public function getProductUrl($product, $additional = array())
{
    if ($this->hasProductUrl($product)) {
        if (!isset($additional['_escape'])) {
            $additional['_escape'] = true;
        }
        return $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, $additional);
    }

    return '#';
}
```

Again there is some checking for url params, and then flow is going to the $product object, `getUrlModel()`

Lets go see what that does:

```
public function getUrlModel()
{
    if ($this->_urlModel === null) {
        $this->_urlModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_url');
    }
    return $this->_urlModel;
}
```

Great, it instantiates a new model (`catalog/product_url`), and in that it call the method `getUrl`

So, first off, there is a potential entry point to extend: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url`, rather than your intended, low level method.

So can you potentially get the require result by doing a rewrite on that class/method ?

So, lets stop there, and backtrack to that helper method also called:

`$this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, $additional);`

Not really going to dig to deep here, but clearly there is another class that you can rewrite.

So ultimately, unless your actual goal is to change the checking of the params in the low level `getProductUrl` in that abstract class, I have just identified two other potential places you can extend, and atain your required functionality (whatever that is)

Hope this helps you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! After studying the function `getAddToCartUrl` realized that I fit replacement function `getAddUrl`, in the class `Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart` substitution which I did. Everything worked as it should. Thank you very much! I am a novice in the study of Magento and this information was very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved and Tested:** 
You can't extend Mage abstract class in your custom module directly but you need to find such mage class which extends your desire mage abstract class, so you extend that class. 
Example: 
- Mage_sales_order_pdf_abstract (you want to extends this class)
Mage_sales_order_pdf_invoice extends Mage_sales_order_pdf_abstract
What you need to do is given below 
CustomModule_model_classname extends Mage_sales_order_pdf_invoice
and now you can override any method from both classes 
- Mage_sales_order_pdf_abstract
- Mage_sales_order_pdf_invoice

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I am not clear about your question.

**Step1:** create a class on your custom  module `which is extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` .

```
<?php 
class YourNameSpace_Yourmodule_Block_Catalog_Product_Myclass extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{

public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = array())
    {
.....................
    }
}
```

**Step2:** `rewrite all class`  which is `extending` **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract**.You need to change those class extending  class

from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` to `YourNameSpace_Yourmodule_Block_Catalog_Product_Myclass`

And `copy all code` from `original` to `new` class  rewrite code and `don't extending parent class and  using copying of all code from main class make the rewrite class work like main class`

From `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` to `YourNameSpace_Yourmodule_Block_Catalog_Product_Myclass`
Suppose in this case, i need `rewrite class  Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` as it **extends** `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstrac`t.
For this List class i have create rewrite class `YourNameSpace_Yourmodule_Block_Catalog_Product_List`

and copy all code from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` to `YourNameSpace_Yourmodule_Block_Catalog_Product_List`

just like :

```
<?php 
YourNameSpace_Yourmodule_Block_Catalog_Product_List {

    /**
     * Default toolbar block name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_defaultToolbarBlock = 'catalog/product_list_toolbar';

    /**
     * Product Collection
     *
     * @var Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
     */
    protected $_productCollection;

    /**
     * Retrieve loaded category collection
     *
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $layer = $this->getLayer();
            /* @var $layer Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer */
            if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
                $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
            }

            // if this is a product view page
            if (Mage::registry('product')) {
                // get collection of categories this product is associated with
                $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
                    ->setPage(1, 1)
                    ->load();
                // if the product is associated with any category
                if ($categories->count()) {
                    // show products from this category
                    $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
                }
            }

            $origCategory = null;
            if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
                if ($category->getId()) {
                    $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                }
            }
            $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

            $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

            if ($origCategory) {
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
            }
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

    /**
     * Get catalog layer model
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer
     */
    public function getLayer()
    {
        $layer = Mage::registry('current_layer');
        if ($layer) {
            return $layer;
        }
        return Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve loaded category collection
     *
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
     */
    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        return $this->_getProductCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current view mode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMode()
    {
        return $this->getChild('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
    }

    /**
     * Need use as _prepareLayout - but problem in declaring collection from
     * another block (was problem with search result)
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();

        // called prepare sortable parameters
        $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();

        // use sortable parameters
        if ($orders = $this->getAvailableOrders()) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        if ($modes = $this->getModes()) {
            $toolbar->setModes($modes);
        }

        // set collection to toolbar and apply sort
        $toolbar->setCollection($collection);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_product_list_collection', array(
            'collection' => $this->_getProductCollection()
        ));

        $this->_getProductCollection()->load();

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Toolbar block
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
     */
    public function getToolbarBlock()
    {
        if ($blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName()) {
            if ($block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName)) {
                return $block;
            }
        }
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, microtime());
        return $block;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve additional blocks html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdditionalHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('additional');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve list toolbar HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getToolbarHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    }

    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addAttribute($code)
    {
        $this->_getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect($code);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPriceBlockTemplate()
    {
        return $this->_getData('price_block_template');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Catalog Config object
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Config
     */
    protected function _getConfig()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Sort By fields from Category Data
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
     */
    public function prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($category) {
        if (!$this->getAvailableOrders()) {
            $this->setAvailableOrders($category->getAvailableSortByOptions());
        }
        $availableOrders = $this->getAvailableOrders();
        if (!$this->getSortBy()) {
            if ($categorySortBy = $category->getDefaultSortBy()) {
                if (!$availableOrders) {
                    $availableOrders = $this->_getConfig()->getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();
                }
                if (isset($availableOrders[$categorySortBy])) {
                    $this->setSortBy($categorySortBy);
                }
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }


}
```

now this rewrite class put it `extends` class `YourNameSpace_Yourmodule_Block_Catalog_Product_Myclass`

```
<?php
class YourNameSpace_Yourmodule_Block_Catalog_Product_List extends  YourNameSpace_Yourmodule_Block_Catalog_Product_Myclass
{
}
```

### The code is not good,but it may works.

**Another Solution,**

Your main issue use of `getAddToCartUrl()`,if we will `not using` this function.as alternative solution  just create `a helper class`  `function`
which will do `same logic like getAddToCartUrl()` .

Suppose my helper class is `YourNameSpace_Yourmodule_Helper_Myadd2cart` and function `getAddToCartUrl`
on this function `copy all code` from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` class function `getAddToCartUrl()`

```
<?php
class YourNameSpace_Yourmodule_Helper_Myadd2cart extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
 public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = array())
    {
        if (!$product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($product)) {
            return $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
        }
        $additional = array_merge(
            $additional,
            array(Mage_Core_Model_Url::FORM_KEY => $this->_getSingletonModel('core/session')->getFormKey())
        );
        if (!isset($additional['_escape'])) {
            $additional['_escape'] = true;
        }
        if (!isset($additional['_query'])) {
            $additional['_query'] = array();
        }
        $additional['_query']['options'] = 'cart';
        return $this->getProductUrl($product, $additional);
    }


}
```

But, you need to change in some position of  this function

**change 1:**

change  from

```
$this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
```

to 
 `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, $additional);`.

Change2:

```
$this->_getSingletonModel('core/session')->getFormKey()
```

from:

```
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()
```

also you add new functions:

```
   public function getProductUrl($product, $additional = array())
    {
        if ($this->hasProductUrl($product)) {
            if (!isset($additional['_escape'])) {
                $additional['_escape'] = true;
            }
            return $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, $additional);
        }
        return '#';
    }

    /**
     * Check Product has URL
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @return bool
     *
     */
    public function hasProductUrl($product)
    {
        if ($product->getVisibleInSiteVisibilities()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Now where you have using $this->getAddToCartUrl there you need to change this code:

from `$this->getAddToCartUrl(yourparams)` to `Mage::helper()->getAddToCartUrl(yourparams)`
and params should be same