# Magento 1.X Override Core Model with subcategory

Tags: magento-1.9

I read a lot of answers of how to override models like:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php
```

And i don't know if i did something wrong but if i tried the same with:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Config/Ordered.php
```

It doesn't works. I have:

```
config.xml
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <model>
                    <config>
                        <rewrite>
                            <ordered>Name_Example_Sales_Model_Config_Ordered</ordered>
                        </rewrite>
                    </config>
                </model>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
```

and in `app/code/local/Name/Example/Model/Config/Ordered.php`:

```
class Name_Example_Sales_Config extends Mage_Sales_Model_Config_Ordered
{
    protected function _getSortedCollectorCodes()
    {
```

I don't know what the correct structure of the path or the xml.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52728/replacement-of-an-abstract-class-in-custom-module

Answer (score 1):

Any Abstract class cannot not be override.

If,you want modify any thing then just copy this model to app/code/local directory...

As Mage_Sales_Model_Config_Ordered want to overwrite.

So Copy Ordered.php from **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Config/** to

**app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Config/** .

As Magento logic: magento have taken file from local folder(app/code/local/) then

from app/code/core/.

Comment: But, what's happend with the patchs?, it'will be applied to the core and never change my local

Comment: For this you have to modified manually if any patches will update this file in core file.

Comment: extending core via copied files to local namespace is really a bad idea. It is best to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

> To rewrite a checkout/cart model :

**app/etc/modules/Namespace_Namemodule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Namemodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout />
            </depends>
        </Namespace_Namemodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Namespace/Namemodule/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Namemodule>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Namespace_Namemodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <cart>Namespace_Namemodule_Model_Cart</cart>
                <rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Namespace/Namemodule/Model/Cart.php**

```
<?php
    class Namespace_Namemodule_Model_Cart extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart {

        public function test() {
            // your logic here
        }
    }
```

Comment: This was not the question ;)